# sonarqube js analysis is successful without details in dashboard

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube

I have configured sonarqube 6.3 in one of our project with java configuration being embedded database, and i use sonar scanner 3.0 with jdk 1.8, and all my java projects gets successfully analyzed with different issue in dashboard. but when i analyze java script(JS) i am not able to get the result in dashboard which shows empty even after the analysis is successful. I just added java script plugin and in sonarproject.property i have changed sonar.source into js. And rest are as usual when compared with java sonar configuration, is there any changes I need to do with the configuration to analyze js source code. I want to know what extra configuration i need to implement apart from java analysis as I would get even js detailed dashboard from my analysis.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add anything relevant-seeming (such as lines that mention JavaScript or SonarJS) from the analysis log.

Comment: Yes Ann its javascript project and code is written in js so kindly request you to tell me the extra configuration required in order to fetch the code result in dashboard

Answer (score 0):

try theses additionnals properties in sonarqube postask jenkins job :

-Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.inclusions=**/web/**/*

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Much appriciated